# Swift 2.0: NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle alternative?

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I am using a datePicker to choose a date, and a label to show the amount of days until the chosen date.

I am Using the ¨_formatter.unitsStyle = .Positional¨ to show the user the number of days that has been chosen, but i dont want the label to say: ¨30 days¨ or ¨30d¨ I only want it to say ¨30¨ Anyone know how i can do it?

None of the UnitStyles previewed on site seems to do that: http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the numeric value, use `NSDateComponents`:

```
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Day, fromDate: NSDate(), toDate: datePicker.date, options: [])
label.text = String(components.day)
```

or, if that number is going to be very large and would benefit from localized formatting, format that number with `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
label.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(components.day)
```